# How to use Terminal command using ExtendScript toolkit

Tags: javascript, shell, applescript, extendscript

I need to use the terminal commands using Javascript on ExtendScript toolkit. For example, using `pdffonts` command on terminal window.

```
pdffonts ~/Desktop/fontlist.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use After Effects you can simply use:

```
system.callSystem('Your command');
```

Or write your command into bat file, and then to use:

```
new File('path/to/bat/file.bat').execute();//for windows
new File('path/to/bat/file.sh').execute();//for mac
```

Comment: I am beginner of javascript, I know only applescript.I need to automate windows and Macintosh operating systems. Is it possible to use terminal commands on extendscript?

Comment: @Annadurai Exactly as I said in my answer. If you use ExtendScript for AfterEffects use the first ex. elsewhere use the second.

Comment: The above comment contains "path/to/bat/file.bat"  -- what is that ? How to give path in extendscript? This command is works for mac?

Comment: @Annadurai If you use the second option you should create bat file and replace the string `path/to/bat/file.bat` to the bat file location. In mac use `.sh` script instead of bat

Comment: The .bat script is for windows. On mac you can save your Applescript as an application and put in the path to the applescript. The path in extendscript is just like it is in applescript, eg. `"/Applications/myApplescript.app"`

Comment: @stib I commented that for MAC he should use `sh`(I just edited my answer to include the `sh` solution). What the OP asked is that he want to run command from the extendscript.

Comment: He says he only knows AppleScript, so he won't know what to do with a shell script any more than a batch script (just quietly, we're probably both wasting our time here).