# Execute shell script from Extendscript Toolkit

Tags: javascript, shell, extendscript

How to execute the shell script file in extendscript toolkit?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you may want to give a little more information if you want an answer

Comment: In shell script file contents are, 
 #!/bin/sh
NAME="Zara"
echo $NAME
 --  then this code, How to execute in extendscript toolkit?
 My output is-->Zara

Comment: @Annadurai Are you serious? I already answered your question! [how-to-use-terminal-command-using-extendscript-toolkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732071/how-to-use-terminal-command-using-extendscript-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

[This wiki gives some ideas](https://github.com/ExtendScript/wiki/wiki/Executing-Shell-Commands):

1. Executing `.term` files with `File.execute`
2. Executing `.command` files with `File.execute`
3. In After Affects, use `system.callSystem('Your command');`